# PHP Loop assistance

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu

I am trying to find out online how to make a form loop based on a dropdown value. So for example, If the dropdown is selected on 2, it will loop a preset form twice, if the option was 3 it would display the form 3 times. This would be helpful because I am trying to get those forms into an array and then use the array to send to phpmyadmin etc. 
Another question is how would I be able to get the value of each form being displayed, unless I can have the code differentiate between the forms, it might just see the values as one instead of two separate if that makes sense.

```
<html> 
<?php 
session_start();
 ?>
<?php include 'AdminHeader.php' ?>
<?php include '../Includes/dbh.inc.php' ?>


<body bgcolor="grey">
    <div class="main">
<form method="POST">
<select name="RaceNum"> 
    <option> Number of Horses </option>
    <option> 1 </option>
    <option> 2 </option>
</select><br />
Horse Number: <input type="text" name="HorseNumber"><br/>
Horse Name: <input type="text" name="HorseName"> 
<button type="Submit" name="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>


<?php 



if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$RaceNum = $_POST['RaceNum'];
$HorseNumber = $_POST['HorseNumber'];
$HorseName = $_POST ['HorseName'];

while($RaceNum < 2){
 $stack = array(
    1 => array( 'Horse Number' => $HorseNumber, 'Horse Name' => $HorseName )
  );
echo "<pre>"; 
print_r($stack); 
echo "</pre>"; 

}
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Can you just use an if statement based on the contents of the $_POST? If all you really want to do is alter the output (display the form 2 or 3 times) based on the selected dropdown, that should do it.

Comment: I figured it out, essentially I had to add a counter variable and that solved it. I knew I've done something like this before, just completely blanked when coding it earlier.